# Is it possible to search for a cookie in IE9 using the console?

Tags: debugging, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I was watching someone use IE9 a while back and they pressed F12 and it pulled up a debugging console.  I could have sworn they issued some sort of command to search for a cookie called "Foobar"

Can this be done?  What is the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.cookie` will return all cookies that do not have `HttpOnly` set.

You can parse it with a regex.

Comment: ty!  How I love stack-overflow.  let me count the ways.